# Short, humorous medieval-era fantasy TV show

Tags: story-identification, tv

I've been racking my brain trying to remember the title of a TV series that didn't last too long (i.e. one season). It was a fantasy type series - knights and kings etc. But the interesting thing was that it was quite tongue in cheek.

I'm thinking it was made in either the US or Canada.

Comment: More information, please -- Fantasy, Short-lived and tongue in cheek -- really not enough to go on.  Do you remember any names?  (Actor OR character) Setting? (Camelot, a Castle, etc.)  Opening Credits?  Anachronisms?  Anything could help..

Comment: What do you mean by "one series"? Do you mean it lasted one *season*?

Comment: @user14111 Yes, that's what he means.  He's from the UK, where 'series' is equivalent to the American use of the word 'season'.

Comment: Knights and kings don't make it fantasy. So, what was fantasy about it?

Comment: Sorry it was a bit vague but that was all I could remember. A few of the actors faces I could remember but not their actual names.

Comment: down vote is a bit harsh. I thought this was the best place to ask scifi experts about a TV series I had seen but couldn't remember lots of details

Comment: Don't take it too personally.  Some people on this site just plain don't like story ID questions.  You can only provide what details you can remember (although I'm impressed the few details you gave were enough for someone to find the right answer).

Comment: @Beofett Yes I'm quite impressed. I didn't want to give any information that might lead people astray. I thought it was late 80s or early 90s. Turns out that was completely wrong.

Comment: @Beofett: Re: impressed...; My sincere thanks to you for the kind words!

Comment: @djm They were earned... you nailed it on the first guess!

Comment: A complete aside - but the comment about the UK usage of "series" to mean the same thing as "season" in the US. I'm finding that "season" is increasingly being used in the UK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Offhand, two shows come to mind, but I really need more info:
Both of these shows were short-lived, medieval and had comedic moments.
[*Wizards and Warriors*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizards_and_Warriors_%28TV_series%29)
[*Covington Cross*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covington_Cross)

Comment: Yes - it was Wizards and Warriors. Thankyou! Searching on the internet I was able to identify Jeff Conway as Prince Erik and Duncan Regehr as Prince Dirk Blackpool. Good job! Thanks